# How to fix google chart not displaying when using array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, charts

I'm setting up a dashboard on my CMS, and I am trying to use the `mysqli_num_rows` function to count posts, users, comments, and categories. I have set two arrays, one for the text, and the other one for the numbers. But when I use the code below, it simply doesn't show any charts.
When I delete the echo it works with the default ['Posts', 1000].

`<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);`

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Data', 'Count'],
    <?php
    $element_text = ['Active Posts', 'Categories', 'Users', 'Comments'];
    $element_count = [$post_count, $categories_count, $user_count, $comments_count];
    for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        echo "['{$element_text[$i]}'" . "," . "{$element_count[$i]}],";
    }
    ?>
    ['Posts', 1000],
    ]);

    var options = {
    chart: {
        title: '',
        subtitle: '',
    }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

`<div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that I used the mysqli_num_rows() function, and put an echo before it, which has gave me an error when I assigned a variable to it, so I removed the echo, and now it works perfectly! The mistake was putting the echo behind the function, which made the chart not appear.